# Objects value not changing in UI with knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using jquery mobile list to represent data in UI, when user click on the the element,it go to details page of that record,

Page stateManage js

```
PageStateManager = (function () {
    var viewModels = {};

    var changePage = function (url, viewModel) {
        alert(">>>>>>>> "+ viewModel.runticketNumber());
        $.mobile.changePage(url, {viewModel: viewModel});
    };

    var registerViewModel = function (viewModelName, viewModel) {
        viewModels[viewModelName] = viewModel;
    };

    var initPage = function(page, newViewModel) {
        var viewModelName = page.attr("data-viewmodel");

        if (viewModelName) {
            if (newViewModel) {
                registerViewModel(viewModelName, newViewModel);
            }

            // get view model object
            var viewModel = viewModels[viewModelName];

            // apply bindings if they are not yet applied
            if (!ko.dataFor(page[0])) {
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel, page[0]);
                viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel);
                ko.validation.group(viewModel).showAllMessages(false);
            }
        }
    };

    var onPageChange = function (e, info) {
        initPage(info.toPage, info.options.viewModel);
    };

    $(document).bind("pagechange", onPageChange);

    return {
        changePage: changePage,
        initPage: initPage
    };
})();
```

Ticket js

```
function RunTicket(jsRunTicket) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(jsRunTicket, {}, this);    
    self.save = function(){
          alert(">>>> " +this.isValid());
    }
```

list view html

```
<div id="listViewDiv">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <!-- ko foreach: tickets -->
                <li data-bind="click:$root.clickList">
                    <h2>Ticket No:<span data-bind="text:action"></span></h2>
                    <p>Item <span data-bind="text:deliveryNetworkName"></span></p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong><span data-bind="text: runTicketType"></span></strong></p>
                </li>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </ul>
        </div>
}
```

View model

```
   var viewModel = {
         clickList : function(val){
            var rt = new RunTicket(service.getRunTicket(val.id));
            PageStateManager.changePage($("#detailsView"),rt);
        }
        seats :[{"action":"SAVE","bsW":null,"date":"2013-12-19T17:11:00","deliveryNetworkName":"XXXXX 7-2932H","runticketNumber":3957,"id":75837},{"action":"SAVE","bsW":null,"date":"2013-12-19T17:11:00","deliveryNetworkName":"XXXXX 7-2932H","runticketNumber":3958,"id":75837}] 
    }
applyBindings(viewModel,document.getElementById("firstPage"))
```

records not changing according to user selection,only contains the first value which user selected from the list,Could anyone help me to find the issue here

Comment: Could you please create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a jsfiddle/plunker/jsbin and describe the error which is observed in the example? Please ensure that the example is as small as possible but still shows your issue. That would make helping you solve your problem a lot easier.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response, I have created an example, but it's not working properly, I really appreciate if you could help me to solve this http://jsfiddle.net/uderox/Hpyca/2/

Comment: You have ordinary javascript syntax errors in your code. When I open the fiddle I see `Expected '}'` in the console. Also, you haven't included all external javascript libraries you try to use. Please make the jsfiddle runnable and I'll have a look.

Comment: please check this http://jsfiddle.net/uderox/Hpyca/3/

Comment: You still have basic issues (which aren't related to your actual question, but which are basic javascript errors) with your fiddle which makes it non-runnable. I suggest pressing `F12` and bringing up the `Console` to see the errors displayed.

Comment: Please look at this, now it is working, I think you could understand my problem,http://jsfiddle.net/uderox/Hpyca/4/, When I click the list element it does not change the value in UI

Comment: You still have your external libraries in the wrong order and also miss one external library which you are using. Fix those first and then look into the following: you have commented out the `clickList` function, so the `click` binding won't do anything. Also, the `changePage` method calls a method which does not exist on the `alert` line. Please fix these issues and see what comes out of it.

Comment: please look in to this  http://jsfiddle.net/uderox/Hpyca/8/ , fixed those errors

Comment: Great! Could you please describe what is not working now? When I click one of the Hospitals, that hospital is selected and the details for it are displayed.

Comment: first click "Hospital1" in the list you will see the "Hospital Id" is "001", click the "Back" link, again click the "Hospital2" "Hospital Id" still "001", It should be "002", it happens Vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you bind to a view model in you call to `ko.applyBindings` in your `PageManager`. After this, the view model will never change. You should make the currently selected hospital into an observable property on your view model and just set that observable property value on page change events.

I have updated your jsfiddle into a working sample which you can find at: http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyca/13/.

Comment: ,Is there a way to make  PageStateManager as a common object?, which can use for the every binding, I'm facing few issues with my previous PageStateManager.I would really appreciate if you could guide me to make this as a common PageStateManager

Comment: If you have new questions, please make a new question on stackoverflow. If it's related to this question/answer you could very well make a comment with a link to the new question. If you feel a need to contact me personally, you can find a `Contact` link on my blog (link in my user profile).

Comment: As you said,your answer(http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyca/13/) working for me, but I need to improve the implementation,since i am bit new to the knockout,I would like to know proper way to reduce the code,I'm trying to make PageStateManager as Generic class which can use for page bindings,In the answer PageStateManager only can use for this situation

Comment: As I mentioned above, this question has been answered. Please make a new question on stackoverflow if you have new questions.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I'll start a new post

Comment: here is the link to new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063828/create-a-generic-class-to-bind-knockout-object-with-pages , I would really appreciate if you could help me