# Create a generic class to bind knockout object with pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am bit new to knockout and jquery mobile, There was a question which is already answered, I need to optimize the PageStateManager class to use generic bindings, currently  PageStateManager can only use for one binding,I would really appreciate if someone can guide me to create a generic class to manage page states with knockout bindings Heere is the working code,http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyca/14/

```
PageStateManager = (function () {
    var viewModel = {
        selectedHospital: ko.observable()
    };

    var changePage = function (url, viewModel) {
        console.log(">>>>>>>>" + viewModel.id());
        $.mobile.changePage(url, {viewModel: viewModel});
    };

    var initPage = function(page, newViewModel) {
        viewModel.selectedHospital(newViewModel);
    };

    var onPageChange = function (e, info) {
        initPage(info.toPage, info.options.viewModel);
    };

    $(document).bind("pagechange", onPageChange);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('detailsView'));

    return {
        changePage: changePage,
        initPage: initPage
    };
})();
```

Html

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="dashBoardPage" data-viewModel="dashBoardViewModel">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: goToList">DashBoard!</button>
</div>
```

New dashboard model

```
    var dashBoardViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.userName = ko.observable('Welcome! ' + "UserName");
        self.appOnline = ko.observable(true);

        self.goToList = function(){
            //I would like to use PageStateManager here 
    //        PageStateManager.changePage($("#firstPage"),viewModel);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel,document.getElementById("firstPage"));//If I click Dashbord button multiple times it throws and multiple bind exception
            $.mobile.changePage($("#firstPage"));  
        }
    }
ko.applyBindings(dashBoardViewModel,document.getElementById("dashBoardPage"));
```

update url : http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyca/14/
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your current fiddle does not have more than one 'page'. It's therefore not really clear what you mean with 'generic' in this case. Could you elaborate further on your problem and example?

Comment: I would like to use PageStateManager with other knockout view models,Please look at the comments, I have updated the url http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyca/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go for creating a `NavigationService` which only handles changing the page and let knockout and my view models handle the state of the pages.

An simple example of such a `NavigationService` could be:

```
function NavigationService(){
    var self = this;

    self.navigateTo = function(pageId){
        $.mobile.changePage($('#' + pageId));
    };
}
```

You could then, in your view models just call it when you want it to navigate to a new page. One example would be upon selection of a hospital (which could be done either via a selection function or by manually subscribing to changes to the `selectedHospital` observable):

```
self.selectHospital = function(hospital){
    self.selectedHospital(hospital);
    navigationService.navigateTo('detailsView');
};
```

Other than the call to the navigationService to navigate, it's just ordinary knockout to keep track of which viewmodel should be bound where. A lot easier than having jquery mobile keeping track of which viewmodel goes where, if you ask me.

I have updated your jsfiddle to show a sample of how this could be done, making as few changes as possible to the HTML code. You can find the updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyca/15/